# Improve BulkInsert Performance

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

I'm loading data from csv file to database of SQL Server using python code

here is my code snippet

```
sql = " BULK INSERT " + str(tbl_name) + "  FROM '" + fl_path + "' WITH (FIRSTROW = 2,FIELDTERMINATOR='',ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n',CODEPAGE = '65001'); "
engine.execute(text(sql).execution_options(autocommit=True))
```

this take 1 minute for 1GB of file to insert into database...
Can anyone suggest me how to improve the performance of Bulk Insert or any other way to insert data which is faster than Bulk Insert

Comment: 1min for a 1gb file doesn't sound that bad?

Comment: I wouldn't complain about that speed.

Comment: Add the `WITH TABLOCK` hint. Read from one physical driver, write to another. Use a binary format rather than CSV text where possible.

Comment: Check the indexes too, bulk works best if there's at most one index. Of course that might not be possible since indexes can be used by other processes. Also, you might wanna change from FULL to BULK recovery model to avoid full logging. But as others said, your speed is pretty good. If you have to upload such big files in such a hurry, perhaps the problem is in the process, not in the data size